# Groovy: How to save the result of a function run within a variable?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm writing a Jenkins pipeline script in Groovy and I'm setting annotation to Mixpanel and for that I have to provide some details such as "RELEASE_DATE", here's the relevant portion of the Jenkinsfile:

```
 MP_API_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXX"
 MP_API_SECRET = "XXXXXXXXXXX"
 MP_EXPIRE = "1588896000"
 MP_APP_PLATFORM = "Android"
 MP_BASE_URL = "http://mixpanel.com/api/2.0/annotations/create?"
 def get_current_time_date() {
     Date date = new Date();   // given date
     Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(); // creates a new calendar instance
     calendar.setTime(date);   // assigns calendar to given date 
     HOUR24 = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); // gets hour in 24h format
     timem = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
     times = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
     newdate = date.format( 'yyyy-MM-dd' );
     println newdate +' '+ HOUR24 + ':' + timem + ':' + times
 }
 RELEASE_DATE = get_current_time_date()
 MP_RELEASE_NOTES = ""
 DESCRIPTION = "${MP_APP_PLATFORM} v${MP_VERSION_NAME} ${MP_RELEASE_NOTES}"
 REQUEST_URL = "api_key=${MP_API_KEY}&date=${RELEASE_DATE}&description='${DESCRIPTION}'&expire=${MP_EXPIRE}"
```

I'm trying to fill the RELEASE_DATE variable with the result of the "get_current_time_date" function but to no avail.

So the things I've tried are:

```
RELEASE_DATE = get_current_time_date
def RELEASE_DATE = get_current_time_date
def RELEASE_DATE = new get_current_time_date
def RELEASE_DATE = { -> get_current_time_date() }
```

Example result of running the function:

```
2016-10-18 12:44:35
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it.

```
 def get_current_time_date() {
     ...your code..
     def result = newdate +' '+ HOUR24 + ':' + timem + ':' + times
     println result
     result
 }
 RELEASE_DATE = get_current_time_date()
```

Comment: Note: I think, your `get_current_time_date` method can replace to `new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`